# MySQL-Join query: How to get the missing values in JOIN (see screenshot)

Tags: mysql, join

I fired a SQL-Query against a db with join and get the result i want with 2 missing values (against 2 Databases).

The problem is that some data is not joined.

This is the screen: http://imageshack.us/a/img805/7764/dbresult.jpg

This is the query:

```
SELECT
    customer_licenses.regkey as regkey,
    sharktoolz_com.zmf3_users.display_name as clientname,
    products.name as productname,
    licensetypes.name as licensename,
    customer_licenses.regname as regname
FROM
    customer_licenses 
LEFT JOIN
    sharktoolz_com.zmf3_users
ON
    customer_licenses.customer_id = sharktoolz_com.zmf3_users.id
LEFT JOIN
    licensetypes
ON
    licensetypes.id = customer_licenses.id 
LEFT JOIN
    products
ON
    licensetypes.product_id = products.id
```

How can i join product to the query? The value exists but is not showed in the result? the product id is the same for every record.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I found the mistake, i refered a false field in the query. Thank you!